# How to set nano default syntax highlighting for files with no extension?

Tags: 12.04, nano, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to set a 'default' syntax highlighting scheme for nano when I'm editing files with no extension such as `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but I can't seem to make it work.

I've copied the `c` syntax highlighting file into `/usr/share/nano/default.nanorc` and then added `include "/usr/share/nano/deafult.nanorc"` to my `~/.nanorc` file but I'm still not getting highlighting for files with no extension.

Anyone know how to enable this?

Comment: Not a dupe. I followed the instructions in the linked question to get syntax highlighting working for several popular extensions. But I'm trying to get highlighting working for file with *no* extension.

Answer (score 9):

You can define this by yourself. Here is a good example from Arch Linux Forums.

Copy the following code and save it in **/usr/share/nano/** as **conf.nanorc**

```
# config file highlighting

syntax "conf" "(\.(conf|config|cfg|cnf|rc|lst|list|defs|ini|desktop|mime|types|preset|cache|seat|service|htaccess)$|(^|/)(\w*crontab|mirrorlist|group|hosts|passwd|rpc|netconfig|shadow|fstab|inittab|inputrc|protocols|sudoers)$|conf.d/|.config/)"

# default text
color magenta "^.*$"
# special values
icolor brightblue "(^|\s|=)(default|true|false|on|off|yes|no)(\s|$)"
# keys
icolor cyan "^\s*(set\s+)?[A-Z0-9_\/\.\%\@+-]+\s*([:]|\>)"
# commands
color blue "^\s*set\s+\<"
# punctuation
color blue "[.]"
# numbers
color red "(^|\s|[[/:|<>(){}=,]|\])[-+]?[0-9](\.?[0-9])*%?($|\>)"
# keys
icolor cyan "^\s*(\$if )?([A-Z0-9_\/\.\%\@+-]|\s)+="
# punctuation
color blue "/"
color brightwhite "(\]|[()<>[{},;:=])"
color brightwhite "(^|\[|\{|\:)\s*-(\s|$)"
# section headings
icolor brightyellow "^\s*(\[([A-Z0-9_\.-]|\s)+\])+\s*$"
color brightcyan "^\s*((Sub)?Section\s*(=|\>)|End(Sub)?Section\s*$)"
color brightcyan "^\s*\$(end)?if(\s|$)"
# URLs
icolor green "\b(([A-Z]+://|www[.])[A-Z0-9/:#?&$=_\.\-]+)(\b|$| )"
# XML-like tags
icolor brightcyan "</?\w+((\s*\w+\s*=)?\s*("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|!?[A-Z0-9_:/]))*(\s*/)?>"
# strings
color yellow "\"(\\.|[^"])*\"" "'(\\.|[^'])*'"
# comments
color white "#.*$"
color blue "^\s*##.*$"
color white "^;.*$"
color white start="<!--" end="-->"
```

Then include this configuration in /etc/nanorc file as

```
## Configuration files (catch-all syntax)
include "/usr/share/nano/conf.nanorc"
```

> The first code line in the snippet includes a regular expression that
> defines for which file names this syntax highlighting should be used.
> Whenever you encounter a config file that is not matched by this, but
> you would still like to open it with syntax highlighting, you can
> manually select this syntax with nano's -Y switch, like so:
>
> ```
> nano -Y conf myConfigFile
> ```

Source: [nano syntax highlighting: catch-all syntax for configuration files](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133595).

Comment: I suggest adding `.nanorc` to the extensions list.  This file highlights itself quite well.

Comment: Unfortunately, using this file make nano extremely slow when navigating through any large conf file.

Answer (score 4):

The nanorc file should have

```
syntax "default"
```

with no regexp after it.

Comment: I found this answer looking up how to set a "default" syntax highlighting configuration. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Nano syntax highlight all files with and **without** extension:

Create backup from default file

```
yes | cp /usr/share/nano/default.nanorc /usr/share/nano/default.nanorc.backup
```

Create a copy from a config file

```
yes | cp /usr/share/nano/sh.nanorc /usr/share/nano/default.nanorc
```

Change syntax extension name to default

```
sed -i -e 's/syntax "sh" "\\.sh$"/syntax "default"/g' /usr/share/nano/default.nanorc
```

Store all .nanrc file in the include file

```
ls -1 /usr/share/nano/*.nanorc | sed 's/^\//include \//' >> ~/.nanorc
```