# How does nano determine syntax coloring for a .txt file?

Tags: command-line, colors, nano

I've recently discovered, that when I open a new text file (extension `.txt`) in `nano`, there is actually a limited syntax coloring:

[image]

That is, if a line starts with number sign/hash, it is colored.

I think this is great, and I really like this (for a txt file, I really don't need any other syntax color, but one marking comment, with the same comment syntax as in `bash`), so I was wondering how/where it was defined.

According to [How to set nano default syntax highlighting for files with no extension?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/415122/how-to-set-nano-default-syntax-highlighting-for-files-with-no-extension), syntax coloring files for nano are in `/usr/share/nano/` directory, and are "imported" via `/etc/nanorc` file.

So, I tried checking:

```
$ grep -r txt /usr/share/nano/
/usr/share/nano/cmake.nanorc:syntax cmake "(CMakeLists\.txt|\.cmake)$"
```

... but the only reference to `.txt` is from `cmake`, and I don't think this is what sets the coloring for `test.txt`.

So, how does `nano` determine the syntax coloring for a `test.txt` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple grepping for `#` in the `/usr/share/nano/` directory gives the following important result among others:

> ```
> $ grep -r "#" /usr/share/nano/
> ...
> default.nanorc:color cyan "^[[:space:]]*#.*"
> ...
> ```

The whole file on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is the following:

> ```
> $ cat /usr/share/nano/default.nanorc 
> ## An example of a default syntax.  The default syntax is used for
> ## files that do not match any other syntax.
>
> syntax default
> comment "#"
>
> # Comments.
> color cyan "^[[:space:]]*#.*"
>
> # Spaces in front of tabs.
> color ,red " + +"
>
> # Nano's name, including version.
> color brightred "(GNU )?[Nn]ano [1-4]\.[0-9][-.[:alnum:]]*\>"
>
> # Email addresses.
> color magenta "<[[:alnum:].%_+-]+@[[:alnum:].-]+\.[[:alpha:]]{2,}>"
>
> # Bracketed captions in certain config files.
> color brightgreen "^\[[^][]+\]$"
> ```

So it is some dynamic highlighter in action.
Next things to check trigger - enter `GNU nano 4.8` to get it in red and some e-mail `<some@email.me>` to get it in magenta. Newer versions have URLs in lightblue and so on. See image below:

[image: Nano with plain file]